# Set the content of PDF to center

Tags: html, css, pdf, tcpdf

I am generating dynamic multicell with string. Like A, B, C etc. I want to center those multicell on the page. I need to make the $pdf->SetMargins() dynamic, which means it will automatically center itself when the content is loaded. This is a code I tried but something is wrong.

```
$pdfWidth = 210;
col = 9; // This is dynamic so it can be any value from 5-20;
    $mar = (($pdfWidth + ($col * 8)) /2)/2;
    $pdf->SetMargins($mar,0,0);
```

Comment: "*Something* is wrong." Somehow you forgot to say what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're dividing by 2 twice. If you take the total width of the page, minus the content and divide that by two you have your desired margin already. Also, don't forget to set the override parameter in SetMargins() to 'true'.

```
$pdfWidth = 210;
$col = 9;
$mar = (($pdfWidth - ($col*8)) /2); //Only one division by 2 is required
$pdf->SetMargins($mar,0,0, true); //the 'true' is necessary or it won't override the default margins

   //VERY IMPORTANT that you set all the above BEFORE adding the page!

$pdf->AddPage();

   //Content of page
```

Now any MultiCell with cell width of 8, as you provided in the example, should be perfectly centered on the page.